# Can we generate email signature page using SharePoint Mysite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, ad, mysites

Hi I am looking for best way to generate email signature including Company logo image in SharePoint (Mysite and AD).

So if user click on a link, it should open up a page with his following details:

1. First name Last Name
2. Job Position, Department
3. Company Name Office
4. Address Telephone no
5. Email ID
6. Company logo

Comment: Do you want do this without programming? I can only think in a solution for this programming a webpart, or a page using javascript programming.

Comment: Hey Thales, I would like to do this using JavaScript.